# how to point to a value in an arrayand use a method on it in java

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I have the following codes, I want to check if the scanned item's value is the same as a value in one of the arrays, but struggling to get the code figured out, does anybody have any idea??
I am really struggling with this whole array coding, I know my code is long but please if you have an idea tell me.
And please only the constructive comments not wiseguys who judge me of my limited java knowledge, as I am a beginner in java.

```
   `package Library;
public class exercising 2 {
public static int id;

public exercising 2(){

    id=0;
    }
    public exercising 2(int _id){
        id=_id; 
  }
    public void set id(int _id){
        id = _id;
  }

    public int get id(){
    return id;
  }
}*`


 * package Library;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class learning {
public static void main(String args[]){

 exercising 2 exercising 1 = new exercising 2();

Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
exercising 2[] exercise = new exercising 2[5];
exercise[0] = new exercising 2(12345);
exercise[1] = new exercising 2(678910);
exercise[2] = new exercising 2(1112131415);
exercise[3] = new exercising 2(1617181920);
exercise[4] = new exercising 2(2122232425);
System .out .print l n("write your id no");

int get Id = Reader . next Int();
boo lean can Loan= false;
int i = 0;
 if(get Id==exercise .hash Code()exercising 1.get id(){
System .out .print l n("you can't loan");;
}
else{
can Loan=false;
System .out. print l n("you're okay");
}
}
}*"
```

Comment: you seem to have invalid syntax everywhere. Unfortunately, this is not good enough to get feedback on it because even if the answer were to be provided it wouldn't work due to other syntax errors which should lead to a compilation failure.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Yes syntax is wrong, I think you are looking for exercise.indexOf(number) >= 0

Answer (score 0):

Names in Java need to be in one word, consisting of letter and digits (underscore is allowed but discouraged). No spaces. So you class should be called `Exercising2`, not `exercising 2`. Similarly, your methods should be called `setId` and `getId`. Names consisting of more words are generally written in so-called camel case, where each word (excpet the first) is capitalized to make it clearer where a new word begins (now there are no spaces). When you want to call a mwthod named `println` you also need to type the name in one word without any spaces.

I am assuming that the backticks, asterisks and double-quote in you code are from your presentation on Stack Overflow and are not present in your real code. They should not be, at least.

Now we’re discussing names, the conventions say `library` with a small l, package names are the exception to the camel case rule, they never have any capital letters at all. Class names should begin with a capital letter, so it’s `Exercising2` (as I have already mentioned) and `Learning`. Variables begin with a small letter, so it’s `reader` with a lowercase r. While you are programming just for yourself, you may think that you don’t need to care, but as soon as you want someone else to look at your code, for instance here on Stack Overflow, you will get more positive response if you try to stick to the conventions.

PS Something’s gone wrong in this line:

```
if(get Id==exercise .hash Code()exercising 1.get id(){
```

If you tell us what you intended, someone may be able to guide you.